# regex, take out punctuation that is not part of a word inside a string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

i have this code:

```
String s="  //wont won't won't ";
String[] w =  s.split("[\\s+\\/,\\.!_\\-?;:]++");
```

i don't the ' to be removed from won't as it is part of the word. help would be appreciated
but //wont i do want // to be removed.

so my question is the following- how do I utilize regex in java to get a certain punctuation not to be removed if its part of a word like "won't" where we have ' , but at the same time keep this-

```
"[\\s+\\/,\\.!_\\-?;:]++"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String[] w = s.split("[\\s+/,.!_\\-?;:]+|\\B'|'\\B");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHjoYn/1/). **Details**:

- `[\s+/,.!_\-?;:]+` - one or more whitespaces, `+`, `/`, `,`, `.`, `!`, `_`, `-`, `?`, `;` or `:`
- `|` - or
- `\B'` - `'` that is at the start of string or immediately preceded with a non-word char
- `|` - or
- `'\B` - `'` that is at the end of string or immediately followed with a non-word char.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/6lUzGy):

```java
String s ="  //wont won't won't ";
String[] w = s.split("[\\s+/,.!_\\-?;:]+|\\B'|'\\B");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w));
// => [, wont, won't, won't]
```

You may get rid of the empty entries at the start if you remove all matches at the start of the string first:

```java
String regex = "[\\s+/,.!_\\-?;:]+|\\B'|'\\B";
String[] w2 = s.replaceFirst("^(?:"+regex+")+", "").split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w2));
// => [wont, won't, won't]
```

Comment: hey, very useful website but this doesn't have an option for java which is the language I am using in this code.

Comment: @GilCaplan It is used here as a demo, not proof that the regex works. If you have any issue with the regex usage in Java, let me know.

Comment: @GilCaplan I added a Java demo - does it work as expected?

Comment: in java, it did not work. I found the solution after some testing.

Comment: @GilCaplan What  do you mean "it did not work"? I provided a demo proving it *works*: my code gets you the expected results. I also explained why it works that way. Well, if you have any Unicode letters, you may need to add `(?U)` flag: `"(?U)[\\s+/,.!_\\-?;:]+|\\B'|'\\B"`

Comment: this is what i used which worked- String[] w =  s.split("\\s+\\'+\\s+|[\\s+\\/,\\.!_\\-?;:]+");

Comment: @GilCaplan That means you wanted to split with `'` that is only located in between whitespace chars, and not with `'` that is not inside words. Glad you got to the solution yourself. Next time please be more precise with regex requirements.